# Neo4php REST API creates node as 'default'

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

In my domain model I have an entity called `User`, and I am creating a new node 
of that type in this manner:

```
public static function register(User $user){
        if(!$user->node)
            $user->node = new Node(Neo4jClient::client());      
        try {
            $user->node->setProperty('__type__', TYPE_USER);
            $user->node->setProperty('username', $user->getUsername());
            $user->node->setProperty('password', $user->getPassword());
            $user->node->setProperty('name', $user->getName());
            $user->node->setProperty('age', $user->getAge());
            $user->node->setProperty('location', $user->getLocation());
            $user->node->setProperty('website', $user->getWebsite());
            $user->node->setProperty('about', $user->getAbout());
            $user->node->setProperty('rating', $user->getRating());
            $user->node->save();

            $user->setId($user->node->getId());

            $userIndex = new Index(Neo4jClient::client(), Index::TypeNode, TYPE_USER);
            $userIndex->add($user->node, 'username', $user->username);

            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And, the node gets created in the database and everything is fine. Except...this way, the node is created as 'default node', as if I was using cypher `CREATE n`, for example. 
What I actually want is to create a node of specific type, as `CREATE (n:User)` but without having to actually use cypher directly.

Any idea how can achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use Neo4j "Labels". Try this:

```
$userLabel = Neo4jClient::client()->makeLabel('User');
$user->node->addLabels(array($userLabel));
```

More information here: https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Labels

Comment: Hmm, I get `Call to undefined method Everyman\Neo4j\Client::makeLabel()` error.

Comment: I just checked and in the `neo4jphp.phar` which I am using (latest one) there is no Label class.

Comment: The PHAR is very out of date, and is being deprecated in the next release of neo4jphp. Please use Composer to install the library.